# Image in inputtext with border in css

Tags: php, html, csc

[image]

IF you see the below picture you can see that the input text consists of image as background.But I want to keep a line in between the text and image.Either by applying image border...or any other trick.Im unable to found exact example or tutorial or trick.Because I applying image as background.So Im unable to apply border...

background: url("~/application/modules/User/externals/images/mail.png") no-repeat scroll  10px 11px #FFFFFF;
    background-size: 20px 20px;

Comment: Why not add the line in the image?

Comment: Show us some HTML and CSS.

Comment: Are you telling to design manually with the color

Comment: I have added the snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for the icons in inputs is using a label element with `for=""` attribute

the for attribute needs to have the id of the input as a value so when you click this element the input get focused

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/rbpLa/1/)

Comment: but Im unable to apply focus.If I keep focus on input elemnt the div was not focusing

Comment: why you need to focus the div? Is this not a form?

Comment: when I click on the input element it should be focused and have to change the border color to orange.So In that case I should have to change the border color of div .Your example helped me a lot but Im unable to get how to focus it.will you please help me for this

Comment: Hey! let me know if this is enough

Oh I didn't ask you , can you use jQuery?

http://jsfiddle.net/rbpLa/5/

Comment: small help can I keep input also in an separate div

Answer (score 1):

In my guessing you can do it by using `border-right:1px solid #333` like,

```
<div>
    <span style="border-right:1px solid #333"><img src="path-to-image" alt=""/></span>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**Alternatively,** you can add a `separator` or `border` in you `images` like,

**CSS**

```
img{
    border-right:1px solid #333;
}
```

Comment: can I keep border for the image instead of taking another span...Because according to our code we couldnt keep that

Answer (score 1):

you could do

input { background-image: url.jpg; box-shadow: 0 4px 0 4px black; }

this should create a solid 4px black right hand side border. Adjust accordingly

Answer (score 1):

you can place image in span and set its right border only ... you can change the span height according to wish, the tag containing span should be applied with the property of overflow: hidden; in order to work in bit proper way,
or simply you can add line to your image.

Comment: can I keep border for the image instead of taking another span

Comment: you can try it in that way as well, but according to this if you want to change the border height, you have to change the image height.

Comment: ok but how to keep that...is it possible to give border for a background image

Comment: you may be placing it in some container like span or anything like it, it would be better to apply border on it.

Comment: everything is fine but the problem is coming with focus

Comment: can you explain further what the problem really is ? you can add padding if your border is getting hidden by focus.

Comment: Or you can remove focus effect as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464180/focusing-and-one-element-should-reflect-to-another-element-in-css?noredirect=1#comment30579603_20464180....here i posted the problem but i didnt get the answer