# Focusing and one element should reflect to another element in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with CSS styling.

Coming to my case. If I focus on input element then the border of a div which is completely outside of that div (which contains input element) should change the border color. For this I have gone through few snippets. But its not working properly. Can I get exact snippet or hints for this? without using JavaScript or jQuery.

```
input[type=email]:focus +  div.emailicon,
{
    border-color: #e86740;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: remove comma (,) and space before div (some browser di'nt suppor that)

Comment: It works, you just put a comma after your selector rule, which is causing it to break the rule entirely: http://jsfiddle.net/f93RB/

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5B4M5/

Comment: @setek is right, instead of just adding the comma you need to remove the + as well.

Comment: @iCezz wait a minute I didn't say anything about removing the `+` :) The `+` is right, it's saying "get the adjacent element if that element is `div.emailicon`.

Comment: ya just now i have seen ...my code is not working again..:(

Comment: btw if you out of focus from the input, will the color remain in the new color or revert back to old color on the div(with emailicon and that has no input)?

Comment: the color is not changing if i focus on the input element also it remain same

Comment: @setek I guess you are right, my silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying this one?

```
div.emailicon { 
     border: 3px solid; 
}

input[type=email]:focus +  div.emailicon
{
    border-color: #e86740;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/f93RB/7/) is the js fiddle you can check it out.

Edited: I change back the , into + as I realise that I made a silly mistake, now it should works finely, which means your initial codes are working fine. Apologise for my silly mistake.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you. Have a great day.

Comment: can you put in your code in jsfiddle so that I can look into it. I tested it and it works fine.

Comment: hmm might the problem with my code I will check it..may something overriding it

Comment: Maybe specifying what browser could help too.

Comment: I edited my answer could you try again and let me know the result.

Comment: your code is fine something is problem with my code it self its not updating...thanx for your help..I need to check where the problem is

Comment: Its not accepting I think It would work only for the adjacent div.....but In my code Its completely outside of the div

Comment: It is difficult to know what when wrong and even solve it if I don't know how you write it. how about you remove the div.emailicon into .emailicon

Comment: how about update your codes above and I will confirm it again.

Comment: Actually It was big code and I couldnt share it public...if you dont mind can I tell you in chat

Comment: could you check your mail

Answer (score 3):

Please remove comma `,`. This will apply border to div next to input focused.

```
input[type=email]:focus +  div.emailicon
{
    border-color: #e86740;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: if possible please provide jsfiddle

Comment: I have given absolute for that div adn placed it beside the input element.will this reflecting the problem

Comment: It should not, but I need your HTML code to be rendered in browser.